# Is it possible to multiple login on the same server with wget?

Tags: bash, shell-script, wget, lynx, cookie

The aim is to enter different accounts at the same time. With **lynx** this is possible using files for each account with the *-cfg=~/file* argument.

**wget** has a *.wgetrc* file that can be configured with:

```
cookies = on
load_cookies = ~/cookies.txt
save_cookies = ~/cookies.txt
```

But unlike **lynx** you don't have the option to invoke it with settings for multiple profiles, it simply loads when **wget** is started with a single cookie for the same server.

I use the script below that should create and maintain cookies without the need to have the *.wgetrc* file, but for some reason that I don't know **is only successful with *.wgetrc*.**

```
#!/bin/bash
LOGIN='login=Account&pass=12345678'
    wget -qO- --save-cookies cookies.txt \
        --keep-session-cookies \
        --body-data="$LOGIN" \
        --method=POST \
        http://example.net/?sign_in=1
# after login
wget -qO- --load-cookies cookies.txt \
        http://example.net/user
```

Based on this information I ask;
_Is **wget** capable of logging in from multiple accounts on the same server?
If yes, how?

***Lynx** is perfectly capable of doing this, but I didn't want to have to use it.*

[image]

Comment: just to get this correct, "enter different accounts": This is not about UNIX accounts or anything, this is about sending different login information in the body of a POST request over HTTP?

Comment: It's about logging into multiple accounts on a site with wget. But without the need to leave an account to enter another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting the cookie loading and saving it in the config file `.wgetrc`, you can specify, for each wget call independently, `--load-cookies filename` and `--save-cookies filename`.

That seems to be what you need. Maybe you also want `--keep-session-cookies` to explicitly ignore when cookies say "delete me when quitting the program".

This information was very quickly looked up in `man wget` by searching for "cookie", just in case you think I know something like all command line flags of `wget` by heart :)

Comment: The arguments;
--load-cookies filename
--save-cookies filename
--keep-session-cookies
It's not working for me, so I use .wgetrc

wget -V
GNU Wget 1.21.3 built on linux-androideabi.

-cares +digest -gpgme +https +ipv6 -iri +large-file -metalink -nls
+ntlm +opie -psl +ssl/openssl

Comment: you can't use .wgetrc if you want different settings for different wget runs. Simple as that. Can you specify in *what* way the argument doesn't work? It's literally exactly the same code as if you put it in your .wgetrc.

Comment: This is the exact content in .wgetrc:
cookies = on
load_cookies = ~/cookies.txt
save_cookies = ~/cookies.txt

If this content is removed, or the .wgetrc file is deleted, login is not performed with the arguments in the command.

But I can see that this only happens with this version of wget in the Termux app for android.

Already on Arch Linux the arguments are working, as in your answer.

Comment: in your .wgetrc you speciify the full path, ~/cookies.txt. In your `wget --load-cookies`, you specify only a relative path. Are you sure there's a cookies.txt in the working directory where you execute things?

Comment: Yes, I use the full path.
The failure occurs only in Termux wget(Android) as described in: https://github.com/sharesourcecode/testing/blob/master/loginlogoff.sh#:~:text=%23%20%2F%25%20wget%20%25%5C%20--%20Simultaneous%20multiple,in%20the%20command%2C%20%5C

Comment: but in your `wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt` call you *do not* use a full path, but a relative one

Comment: Still not working on android. I've already marked the issue as resolved, as this works on my Linux. Thank you for your help.